# c# view specified amount of data in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, entity

Right now, using entity model I am loading data in datagridview as follows:

```
                        var context = new NewEntities();
                        BindingSource bi = new BindingSource();
                        bi.DataSource = context.Table_Name;
                        dgvLoadTable.DataSource = bi;
                        dgvLoadTable.Refresh();
```

In this way, all the records of a table is loaded in the datagrid. What I want to do is, specify the number of records I want to see in a combobox (like:500, 1000....all) and load corresponding amount of data in datagrid. Any suggestion, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could try the .Take() function.

eg, This would give you 50 items:

```
bi.DataSource = context.Table_Name.Take(50).ToList();
```

Granted, that isn't very meaningful without some other selection criteria, or ordering, etc.

Comment: Thanks, It works fine. Any idea how do I use Take() with the following line?
bi.DataSource = context.GetType().GetProperty(TableName).GetValue(context, null);
Here, var TableName = cboSelectTable.Text.ToString();

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Skip() and Take() to Skip a number of rows (for paging) and Take a certain number, respectively:

```
var context = new NewEntities();
BindingSource bi = new BindingSource();
//skip the first 100 rows and takes the next 50
bi.DataSource = context.Table_Name.OrderBy(x=>x.Id/*Some unique ID*/).Skip(50).Take(100);
dgvLoadTable.DataSource = bi;
dgvLoadTable.Refresh();
```